# HTMX does not re-process sse-swap attribute for Server-Sent-Events

Tags: javascript, html, server-sent-events, htmx

I have a dashboard with various system info I'd like to visualize on a website. For simplicity I decided to use HTMX to send real-time performance metrics to the website via
Server-Sent-Events, specifically the `sse` extension.

On this website I have a variable number of tables which are supposed to be populated during the running of the application. At first the table is sent via SSE without any entries and as the data comes in, a row is supposed to be added to the table. The table has an `sse-swap` attribute which is supposed to listen for rows intended for that specific table, but the `sse-swap` attribute isn't listened on by HTMX.

When I tested it by inserting the table into the index.html statically, adding the rows worked. I even tried manually re-processing the newly added attributes with the JavaScript API `htmx.process(element)` but that also didn't register the `sse-swap` attribute of the table.

Code to reprocess new elements:

```js
htmx.onLoad(function(elt){htmx.process(elt)})
```

Table structure which is added in dynamically with the event: `document`

```html
<div class="card col-lg-6 border-0 mx-1 shadow-lg rounded-0" id={{name}}>
    <div class="card-body w-100 p-0">
      <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-sm m-0">
        <thead class="small">
          <tr>
            <th class="small">Component</th>
            <th class="small">URL-Wait</th>
            <th class="small">Serialization</th>
            <th class="small">Deserialization</th>
            <th class="small">Annotator</th>
            <th class="small">Component-Total</th>
            <th class="small">Worker-Total</th>
            <th class="small">Size</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody sse-swap="{{ name }}_measurement" hx-swap="beforeend">
          
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Table row which is supposed to be appended to the -element (but isn't right now) with the event: {{ name }}_measurement

```html
<tr>
    <td class="small"> {{ component }} </td>
    <td class="small"> {{ urlwait }} </td>
    <td class="small"> {{ serialization }} </td>
    <td class="small"> {{ deserialization }} </td>
    <td class="small"> {{ annotator }} </td>
    <td class="small"> {{ component_total }} </td>
    <td class="small"> {{ worker_total }} </td>
    <td class="small"> {{ document_size }} </td>
</tr>
```

Index.html which is the starting point where the connection is made:

```html
<div hx-ext="sse" sse-connect="/document_update"class="container-fluid m-1 p-1 rounded-0"  id="componentDashboard">
        <div class="row mb-2 mb-xl-3">
          <div class="col-auto d-none d-sm-block">
            <h3><strong></strong></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div sse-swap="document" hx-swap="beforeend" class="row gap-4 flex-nowrap overflow-auto" id="scrollable-components">
          
        </div>
      </div>
```

I appreciate any suggestions on how to deal with this. Preferably with minimal Javascript :)

Comment: by "added after the table structure " you mean appended to the `<tbody>` perhaps not added after the table?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Yes, that is what I meant.